# My java file is one line of blank spaces? Common solutions haven't worked

Tags: java, eclipse, whitespace, corruption, corrupt

I made an account just for this because no existing Stack Overflow question seems to answer this and it's difficult to google this question.

I walked away from my computer for perhaps 45 minutes - when I walked away, my code was fine - and upon return, I saw that my .java source file (I'm using Eclipse) was just *one extremely long line* of blank spaces. No code visible, but the .java file is still the same 9KB it once was, and I can open it in text editors just fine... except the text editors also show a string of what appear to be blank spaces. No, local history isn't working. What on Earth is going on here? And how do I fix it? Clearly the information still exists *somewhere*, but how do I access it?

No, I don't have a recent backup. Walk of shame.

Here's an attempt to copy-paste the contents of the file:

Comment: Was your computer locked while you were away? Just wondering...

Comment: Sounds like a bad save.  Can you try uploading the file to a file sharing site?

Comment: Have you tried to to select the text, right click->source->correct indentation (or format) ?

Comment: Michael Easter, I did go through the lock screen when I came back, yes, but it wasn't "hard locked", so to speak - nothing had shut down as a result.

@CeePlusPlus, http://www.mediafire.com/file/hqc4xbfnaosltsn/Bagels_Updated.java/file (don't mind the name, I forgot to change it, haha).

ScaryWombat, thanks for the suggestion, but it seemed to do nothing.

Comment: *"Clearly the information still exists somewhere, but how do I access it?"*  -  How so "clearly"?  The information could be gone for ever, everywhere.

Comment: The uploaded file contains just NUL characters.  There is no useful information in it.  If you are going to recover the original Java code you will need to get it from somewhere else.  (But my guess is that it is gone ...)

Comment: Are you sure the local history is empty - right click on the file and select "Replace With > Local History..." (**not** Restore from Local History which is for deleted files).